# ScanSnap S1500M Time-out

Tags: scanning

Not sure why, but after about 5 minutes of scanning, my ScanSnap just bails on me. I would use their documentation, etc. but nobody knows what this error code is so I wanted to seek the geniuses here and I think it likely that others must have had this problem.

When I’ve used this scanner with another computer it works fine.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software many times, but I’m not sure I’ve completely uninstalled the software because it still retains my custom profile, which I believe may be the source of the problem. Maybe that would be a great first step is to get a complete list of the files to uninstall, since there must be at least a portion of it which is manual.

[image]

```
Time-out occurred during communication. (0xd0020002)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this "other computer" running OS X or another OS?

Comment: From http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products", so this question is definitively on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I have one of these scanners and have noticed it can be sensitive to how it's connected on the USB bus. If the problem continues, try connecting it directly to a USB port on your Mac instead of through a hub (if it's not already directly connected).

Answer (score 2):

There is a [more recent update](http://www.fujitsu.com/global/support/computing/peripheral/scanners/software/mac-mg32.html) to your scanner software. Sorry for the one liner, but I sometimes take pity on weak Googlers.